# kivy SQL and Label

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, kivy

I'm trying to make a mobile application for a little community, in `Python`, `Kivy` and an online `SQL` database.

I found it easier to have a large database with several table and people interacting with it.

There will be 6 table at least and the main "page" will show each of them
the queries will be like c2.execute('SELECT texte FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC')

My question is how in `kivy` ( or in `.kv` ) I can show the return of `c2.execute` in a Label ?
Or in any output that could be designed.

Comment: Well...what's your problem with showing your output in a Label? Do you know how to make a Label? Do you know how to set its text? Please post an example demonstrating the part that you get stuck on.

Comment: The part i'm stuck on is not how to make a label , it his how to give him text that result from a query cursor.fetchone()

Comment: Right, but what's your problem with doing that? Post an example, as above.